# Let $f: (\mathbb{R}, d) \to (\mathbb{R}, d')$ where $d$ is the usual metric and $d'$ is the discrete. Determine if $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $f: (\mathbb{R}, d) \to (\mathbb{R}, d')$ where $d$ is the usual metric and $d'$ is the discrete. Determine if $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous.

In order for $f$ to be continuous I have to have that $$d'(f(x),f(y)) \ < \varepsilon, \text{ when } d(x,y) < \delta, \text{ for $\varepsilon, \delta >0.$}$$

Now $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ and from the discrete metric we have that $d'(f(x),f(y)) \ < \varepsilon$ is only true when $f(x)=f(y)$ which would imply that $d'(f(x),f(y)) = 0$ otherwise we would need to pick $\varepsilon >1$ which wont' work since it's supposed to work for all $\varepsilon$.

We have some cases where the continuity seems to hold for example when $x=2, y=-2$ we have that $f(x)= f(2) = f(-2)=f(y) = 4$, but I'm not sure that the continuity holds for all points. I feel like it doesn't, but I'm not sure how to show this?

Answer (score 1):

No.  $f^{-1}(0)=0$ is not open.  But in the discrete topology points are open.

---

Or, you could use the definition that the inverse image of any closed set has to be closed.  Take an open interval in the discrete topology.  It's closed (everything is).  But it's preimage is not closed, as you can check.  For instance, $f^{-1}((0,1))=(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.

Comment: Why consider $f^{-1}(0)=0$?

Comment: It's the preimage of an open set which isn't open.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost proved that $f$ is  not continuous **at any point**. If it is continuous at $x$ then $x^{2}=y^{2}$ whenever $|x-y| <\delta$. (You could take $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon =1$). But we get a contradiction by taking $y=x+\frac  1 n$ with $n$ sufficiently large.

We can choose $n$ such that $\frac  1n <\delta$ and $\frac {2x} n+\frac 1 {n^{2}} \neq 0$ (or $x \neq -\frac 1 {2n})$.